# ListObjects request from Salesforce to AWS S3 results in "refused to connect" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, salesforce, aws-sdk-js

I'm developing a Salesforce component that makes a request to AWS S3 using the AWS JavaScript SDK.

When making the request below, I receive the console error `Refused to connect to https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/list-type=2&prefix=00Q5e000001Vx7iEAC`

```js
s3.listObjectsV2(
  {Bucket:'mybucket', Prefix: component.get('v.recordId')},
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
);
```

I am confused why this is happening since I am able to make requests using `s3.getSignedUrl()` without any errors.

What do I need to do to allow this request from Salesforce to AWS?

Comment: `getSignedUrl` doesn't make actual HTTP requests to the S3 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jellycsc said, I realized that the requests were different.

Turns out that I just needed to add `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com` to my CSP trusted sites in Salesforce.